# How to Remove White border of Custom Dialog box in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to Remove White border of my custom Dialog box.I find a lot on Stack Overflow.But Still not get the Solution.How to Remove this white Border.Please Someone help me for my this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

try this use Dialog Instead of AlertDialog.Builder and for remove border line from Dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

and You have to replace the dialog's window content view. I think you can use this in your dialog constructor:

```
this.getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_view);
```